# Removing and ignoring a versioned item, while preserving users' local copies

Tags: svn, ignore

There is a file, let's call it `fileToBeIgnored`, that is versioned in SVN and shouldn't be.  I understand that `svn:ignore` only prevents the addition of files to the SVN repository and already versioned files will keep on getting versioned whether they match the pattern or not. I'm perfectly okay with removing `fileToBeIgnored` from the SVN repository and adding it to its directory's `svn:ignore` property.

My problem is, if I do that, when other users do their next update, their SVN client will try to remove their local copy of `fileToBeIgnored`. I don't want that; instead, I would like for everyone's currently existing local copy to be preserved.

Is there a way to remove a file from the SVN repository without it being removed from a user's local copy on subsequent update?

Comment: there is a changelist called `ignore-on-commit` that will keep the file versioned but not try to commit it later. However, not all clients are supporting this as far as I know.

Comment: @Brain, if you are the only person who does not need the file why make the change in the repo ? or do you mean any new checkouts should not have the file fileToBeIgnored ?

Comment: fileToBeIgnored is a config file.  Once upon a time, we thought we wanted it centrally managed.  Over time it has become clear that individual developers will have variations in their local copy of that file.  If everyone remembers not to check in their file, everyone else is happy.  But, occasionally, accidents happen.  Just looking to reduce the possibility for human error.

Answer (score 1):

Do the commit with the delete and the property change; then there are two scenarios:

1. Another dev has no local changes. He updates, and his file is deleted. He can just `svn cat` the appropriate revision of the file to his working copy again.
2. Another dev has local changes. When he updates, he gets a tree conflict. He can `svn resolve --accept=working fileToBeIgnored` to resolve the conflict, then `svn rm --keep-local fileToBeIgnored` to avoid adding the file to version control again, while keeping his local copy.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to remove a file from the SVN repository without it being removed from a user's local copy on subsequent update?

I don't think so.

What I would do is to send a mail to everyone notifying them of the change. Whoever doesn't manage to keep a copy on the side can always get an earlier version of the file from the repository.

Comment: Mmmm... it *might* be possible if you removed the file, and added a `svn:ignore` at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Move the file to a different folder.
Remove from SVN.
Update.
Add the file back to the folder.
Commit with svn:ignore.